# import email data to the DB

Tags: php

I built support system (web) where my helpdesk can open new tickets/issues.
I want my clients to be able to send email with the issue text and file attache, to specific email address, and new ticket will be opened in my system.
For that I need to know how to scan the folder and how to add the email data to my DB.

what do I need to look for, in the internet, for that? what is the subject?
(I'm using PHP)

Comment: It is a basic principle of this site that you ought to try before you go asking the community to write your code for you (or in this case, map out your plan of research). It does not appear that you have tried anything beyond trying to submit a question to Stackoverflow (which, while an operational success, may soon be rendered a failure by the voting of the community).

Comment: but I don't know what to search...I need the title of my issue @BrianWarshaw

Comment: I say this a lot on here, but if you don't even know where to begin to search or code for something like this, you're probably starting with something that is way beyond your beginner's skill level. Instead of trying to learn to program by tackling a problem, spend some time learning fundamentals. A good book or online resource will naturally use learning by example to help, but will also instill strong fundamentals.

Comment: "parse incoming emails by subject" would be starting point for me

Comment: Something like https://www.google.com/#q=php+check+pop3+imap ?

Comment: thanks. I think I fund something @AxelAmthor

Comment: @BrianWarshaw - thats not true at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind is to pop the most recent emails if you have pop3 set up or use imap functions. I did something similar to this using c# using openpop.net. So that could be a starting point.

Answer (score 2):

As the other's have commented, it's likely a larger task than you're ready to handle. But it doesn't hurt to try.

If I was tasked with the job, I'd take advantage of Gmail (for it's spam reducing features and large storage) to accept incoming email. From there, you simply need to setup a script that connects to your email account and processes the email for storage in your database.

Normally I recommend a solid library for making the job easier and cleaner, but I have a suspicion that you may not be familiar with OOP. If you at least know how to utilize classes, then check out Github:
https://github.com/search?l=PHP&q=imap&ref=searchresults&type=Repositories

Otherwise, if you're new and don't mind writing something "messy" then the following should at least point you in a good direction:

---

**Connecting & retrieving emails for IMAP:**

- http://www.php.net/imap
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-open.php

---

**Fetching/processing attachments:**

(note that attachments are part of the email body)

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-fetchstructure.php

---

**Storing attachments (in the filesystem):**

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

---

There's plenty of Googling left for you to do. So go forth and make a lot of mistakes. Read the manual. Kick yourself for not having read it sooner, then go make more mistakes. Isn't that how most of us learn?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method, using the cURL to fetch the emails from Gmail server through feed atom. XML response will return and we can convert it to HTML.

http://www.code4share.net/items/get-unread-email-in-gmail-by-php/XRGXVVh.html